# Create DbQuery out of View table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, sql-view, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to create a DbQuery of ExtendedStudent, from SQL View which was constructed form 2 diffrent tables (see code SQL below).

I have looked at the following posts:

[Entity Framework Core Query Types](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/query-types#relationships) And [EF Core 2.1 Query Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt847184)
Both have used a model with a navigation propery in it, and then succeeded to fetch it from the Fluent Fluent API.
But When i tried to do so too, i got exception such as "Invalid column name 'PrefixId1'

The models I use are:

```
public class ExtendedStudent {

    public int IdNumber {get; set;}

    public string FirstName {get; set;}

    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public virtual Prefix Prefix {get; set;}

    public int Score {get; set;}
}

public class Prefix {

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id {get ;set;}

    [required]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The applicationDbContext.cs file is:

```
public class ApplciationDbContext : DbContext{

    DbSet<Prefix> Prefixes {get; set;}

    DbQuery<ExtendedStudent> ExtendedStudents {get ;set;}

    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {

        builder.Query<ExtendedStudent>.ToView("ExtendedStudent");
        builder.Query<ExtendedStudent>.HasOne<Prefix>().WithMany();
    }
}
```

At last, I tried to fetch the data like this.

```
var students = applciationDbContext.ExtendedStudents.Include(v => v.Prefix).ToList();
```

I have created the ExtendedStudents view in SQL like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [Organization].[ExtendedStudent] AS
SELECT [TableA].[Student].[FirstName]
        ,[TableA].[Student].[LastName]
        ,[TableA].[Student].[PrefixId]
        ,[TableA].[Student].[IdNumber]
        ,[Evaluation].[Student].[Score]
FROM [TableA].[Student] AS [Students]
INNER JOIN [Evaluation].[Student] ON [Evaluation].[Student].StudentId = [TableA].[Student].[IdNumber]
```

I have tried to add a PrefixId property to ExtendedStudent, or add foreign key, But nothing have worked.

I got an error saying

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occured in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Invalid column name 'PrefixId1'.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
builder.Query<ExtendedStudent>.HasOne<Prefix>().WithMany();
```

with `.HasOne<Prefix>()` you are telling EF Core to create many to one relationship *without* navigation property at each end.

But the navigation property `ExtendedStudent.Prefix` already implies relationship, hence EF Core assumes a *second* relationship with default FK property and column name `PrefixId1` (because `PrefixId` is already used by the "other" relationship implied from the navigation property).

To fix that, pass the navigation property to the relationship configuration:

```
builder.Query<ExtendedStudent>.HasOne(e => e.Prefix).WithMany();
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work, But in my case I use lazyloadingProxies, so I added the virtual keyword to the navigation property, But I recieved an error saying  "getting value from 'Prefix' on 'Castle.Proxies.ExtendedStudentProxy --> Unable to track an instance of type 'ExtendedStudent' because it is a query type, Only entity types may be tracked. Do you know why it is tracked?

Comment: I guess you should remove the `virtual` from this property of `ExtendedStudent`, because `ExtendedStudent` is query type and should not be proxied. At least this is how I read the error message.

Comment: Anyway, that's a different issue, you can post it as separate question if you wish.